# ValidFormBuilder outputs strange javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, validform

I'm trying to get a small Proof of Concept working with ValidFormBuilder. 
I created a form with just a text area. Very simple, but the HTML that ValidFormBuilder generates is not valid.
There's javascript-code at strange places, it looks like rubbish and there's a lot of duplicate code in the generated HTML.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

You can see the strange behavior over here: http://zorginformatiegroep.nl/form/test.php

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use ValidFormBuilder\ValidForm;

$objForm = new ValidForm("hello", "Required fields are printed in bold.", "/test.php");

$objForm->addField(
"message",
"Your Message",
ValidForm::VFORM_TEXT,
array(
    // Make this field required
    "required" => true
),
array(
    // Error message when required state isn't met
    "required" => "This is a required field"
),
array(
    "cols" => 20,
    "rows" => 10
)
);

//*** Generate form output
if ($objForm->isValid() && $objForm->isSubmitted()) {
    $strOutput = $objForm->valuesAsHtml();
} else {
    $strOutput = $objForm->toHtml();
}

echo $strOutput
?>
```

Comment: actually the $strOutput is echo'ed within some HTML-code but I can't manage to add it to the post.

Comment: Which version are you using? The [latest 3.2 release from GitHub](https://github.com/neverwoods/validformbuilder)?

Comment: Update; there seems to be a bug in the recent 3.2 release. Your code runs just fine when using ValidForm Builder 3.1.0. The only difference between these releases is the massive amount of documentation added in 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3.2 release of ValidForm Builder was broken, you found that bug and I created the issue here:

https://github.com/neverwoods/validformbuilder/issues/14

I've bugged the problem and our team has released a new version: `3.2.1`
If you've installed ValidForm Builder using Composer, depending on your configuration you should be fine by running `composer update`.

This should answer your question.